# Access Grails domain class from GroovyShell script

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm trying to use [`GroovyShell`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/GroovyShell.html) to evaluate some snippets of code from within a Grails application, but I don't seem to be able to access our Grails domain classes. For example when I try to evaluate something like this:

```
Eval.me("my.package.MyDomainClass.get(1)")
```

I see an error like this:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: my for class: Script1
```

Any thoughts on how I can get this to work?

Thanks.

Comment: is this the GroovyShell you get after running `grails shell`?  http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/shell.html

Comment: I mean the `GroovyShell` class - a class that can evaluate arbitrary groovy code: http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/GroovyShell.html. `Eval.me` (http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/Eval.html) is a convenient static method for instantiating an instance of that class and calling `evaluate` on it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured out how to get this working. By default a `GroovyShell` instance clearly evaluates the script in its own classloader, so none of your Grails artefacts are available. There's an alternative constructor where you can pass in another classloader, so this does what I need within the context of a Grails application (when running inside a `grails console`, for example):

```
def shell = new GroovyShell(this.class.classLoader)
shell.evaluate("my.package.MyDomainClass.get(1)")
```